# Best way to request initial Auth Token

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, oauth-2.0

We are in the middle of converting our entire web infrastructure to use JWT as our Bearer auth tokens and I added a global interceptor on our `$httpProvider` that will read the token from a service that was previously (in a resolve for the root state of our app) fetched from our Auth server.

The problem is that I get a circular dependency because the initial call to `GET /api/oauth/token` uses the `$http` service which uses my interceptor. Therefore, the only way I think I can do this is to not use `$http` in that initial request, right?

What is the correct way to do this? It feels wrong to use jQuery here to make the AJAX call, but is that the best way?

```
app.factory('AuthProvider', function($http, $q){
    var service = {};
    var _token = null;

    service.getToken = function(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        // the use of $http here is what causes this issue
        $http({
            method:'GET',
            url:'/api/oauth/token'
        }).then(function(res){
            _token = res.result;
            deferred.resolve(_token);
        }, function(res){
            deferred.reject(res);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }

    service.readToken = function(){
        return _token;
    }

    return service;
});
```

Comment: Show code of your interceptor also. Are you saving the token value locally somewhere like as a cookie/ in localStorage/sessionStorage? If yes then you can have that condition check in your interceptor request property